# Is there any limitation on string length defined in variable argument list

Tags: c

I have doubt regarding variable argument list,is there any limitation on the lenght of char string defined as one of argument to variable list.for example

```
void ShowVar( int a,char *szTypes, ... );

int main() {
   ShowVar( 4, "Test","string-size");
}
```

Now my question, is there any limitation on the string size here?

Comment: Why think that this is the case?

Comment: No, and why should there be? if you want to deal with 100 chars max, just add a `char active[101]; strncpy(active, szTypes, 100);` to your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit imposed by the C language on how long a C string can be (as C strings are basically arrays of `char` with a NUL character at the end). As you can see, the type of the argument is `char *`, i.e., pointer to `char`. This means that the string itself is not passed as an argument, but rather a pointer to its first character—the length of the string is therefore irrelevant for the function call.

(In practice there will of course be a limit from the computer architecture and platform, but these limits are very high compared to typical string arguments.)

Comment: I guess this sting constant is going to store in code segment and you have well defined size of a code segment.is n't it?

Comment: If I give it the srting size more than 64k ,there should be some exception generated .

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar There may of course be limits to the length of a string that arise from the way that it is stored, but that limit exists whether or not it is ever used as the argument of a function, or the argument of a function with a variable number of arguments.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar The whole string is not passed as an argument, only the pointer to its first character (hence the type `char *` for the argument) -> it makes no difference for the function how long the string is. If there is a limit, e.g., on the length of string literals (`"string"`) then that limit is what is causing the error, not the fact that the string literal is used as the argument of this function.

Comment: Fine @Arkku ,got your point but what is the way to test that string literal has some limit or not?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar That would be a different question, and I don't know of a good answer. The C standards guarantee some small minimums for max. length of string literals, but the compiler is not required to enforce any minimum, and I don't know of a way (e.g., preprocessor macro) to check for the limit. If I recall correctly, C99 guarantees only 4K for the string literals, but many compilers will support more (the 64K you mention sounds like such a limit).

Comment: Thanks Arkku for your time,will post other question regarding the string literals size limit.

Answer (score 3):

No.

All that gets passed in the call is character pointers after all.

The size of each pointer is constant, regardless of how many characters are in the string it points at.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically No.
The argument `char *` is just a pointer to the array of characters.