# What is the way to find the String literal size limit

Tags: c

I wanted to know what are the ways to find out the String literal size limit.I guess different compilers do provide the max size limit of string literal but how do I find it programmatically or there is some standard header files which maintain this size limit as some macro??

Answer (score 3):

I checked the C99 draft, all it says is that at least 4,095 characters should be supported in a string literal; there doesn't seem to be a maximum length. This makes sense to me; why impose such a limit?

I really don't think you can "detect" this at run-time. Of course you should be able to detect it, crudely speaking, at compile-time by checking if the compilation succeeds. Write a program that generates a program containing a string literal of a given length, then try to build that output and iterate until building fails. Of course you will only have learnt something about your particular compiler, not a general lesson.

Perhaps you should try to state your actual problem, it seems you're kind of [hinting at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929545/is-there-any-limitation-on-string-length-defined-in-variable-argument-list) instead.

Comment: Thanks unwind for the respose .Yes unwind ,I am also thinking of doing the same way you suggested ,more of hint and trail method.My actual problem is for string literal which is very long (yet to find out its size) ,one of the handler is genrating exception.

Comment: ,One more thing ,I just checked my make file.I couldn't find any flag which suggested I am using c99 feature and my gcc version is 4.3.2 which I believe used c89 as deafult and supported litreal size is some what less here.Would you like to comment on the same?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar C89 only guarantees 509 characters for string literals, but like C99 it does not specify any maximum that the compiler can support. So a standards-compliant compiler is free to support string literals of any length, it is just not _required_ to support more than 509/4095 in C89/C99.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar In any case, I agree with unwind that you only seem to be hinting at the actual problem you are having… I would suggest that you just go by the standard and assume that 4095 is the maximum length of a string literal (even though your compiler is likely to support more), and then ask the question of how to design your program around that limit (e.g., perhaps all of this is a good indicator that a string literal is not the right way to store the amount of data you have).

Comment: Ok Arkku , I take your suggestion .Also,would you confirm this statement that By default gcc version 4.3.2 uses c89 feature and my way to confirm it in make file is ok?

Comment: One more thing ,the platform I am working on is quite a complex one and may be it is already designed in way that maximum limit of literal is 509/4095 and that is why I am getting this exception after crossing the limit defined.